# Unable to convert project into static library in xcode4

Tags: objective-c, ios6, xcode4.3, static-libraries

I am trying to wrap up a 3rd party project into a static library, so that i can use it as a subproject. But i am constantly running into "parse issue" errors pointing me to one of the framworks that the 3rd party has created. I am not able to figure out[image] the solution to this.

[image]

Comment: Hmm.. I am new to stackoverflow. Thanks for letting me know that. Probably it's the reason no one bothers to answer my questions. Anyways, this is really urgent and I would be very grateful if somebody helped me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is `UIImage*` is not recognized by the compiler. You can see a little mark under it, and it is not in the same color as `SFThumbnailFetcher*` in the same line.

The `UIImage` class is defined in the **UIKit Framework**, so you have to import it before.

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
```